# Creating and using a 2 dimensional array

Tags: arrays, multidimensional-array, automated-tests, robotframework

I need to define a 2 dimensional array variable.
I have been able to use a list variable but now the project I'm working on requires an array.

How is this done?
How can I "loop" through the 2 dimensional array?

Comment: When you say "2 dimensional array", how exactly do you plan on using it? What are the dimensions? Are they integers? A list of lists is a two dimensional array, will that suffice? Does it have to be a literal 2 dimension array, or can you use a dictionary where the keys _look_ two-dimensional? Can you give us an example of the type of data you need to manage?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using a list of lists. You can use the [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) to access an item in the inner list.

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
@{colors}         red    green    blue
@{animals}        cow    pig    dog
@{things}         ${animals}    ${colors}

*** Test Cases ***
2-Dimensional List
    Log List    ${things}
    Log    The ${things[0][1]} is ${things[1][1]}
```

List length is 2 and it contains following items:
0: [u'cow', u'pig', u'dog']
1: [u'red', u'green', u'blue']

The pig is green

Comment: thanks for the great answer! One more thing, can I loop through the the dimensions: cow, red: cow, green.... pig, red.....?

Comment: I've been using this approach because it seems the only one that creates something close to an actual table. HOWEVER, it becomes a big problem if you have, for example, 256 colors. Either you have a huge line or, if you brake it, the table visualization is gone. IMHO, not having decent data tables is kind of a shame for the Robot Framework team.

Answer (score 2):

## Using lists

Robot's term for an array variable is "list". You can use `@{...}` to designate a variable as a list. Here's an example that shows how to create a list in a variable table, and how to do it within a test using the [Create List](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/libraries/BuiltIn.html#Create%20List) keyword:

```
*** Variables ***
| # create a list in a variable table
| @{Colors} | red | orange | green | blue

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of using lists

| | # create an array inside a test
| | @{Names}= | Create list | homer | marge | bart

| | # Verify that the elements are arrays
| | Length should be | ${Colors} | 4
| | Length should be | ${Names} | 3
```

To create a two dimensional list, you can create a list of lists:

```
| | ${array}= | Create list | ${Names} | ${Colors}
```

The [extended variable syntax](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#extended-variable-syntax) lets you access individual elements:

```
| | log | element 1,1: ${array[1][1]}
```

For more information, see the section titled [List variables](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#list-variables) in the [Robot Framework User Guide](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html)

## Using dictionaries

You can use a dictionary to simulate a multi-dimensional array. For example:

```
*** Settings ***
| Library | Collections

*** Test Cases ***
| Example of using a dictionary to simulate a two dimensional array
| | ${array}= | Create dictionary 
| | ... | 0,0 | zero, zero
| | ... | 0,1 | zero, one
| | ... | 1,0 | one, zero
| | ... | 1,1 | one, one
| | Should be equal | ${array["1,0"]} | one, zero
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm actually looking for a 2 dimensional array. Sorry I wasn't clearer about it in the post.

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to loop through a list of lists:

```
*** Settings ***
Library           Collections

*** Variables ***
@{colors}         red    green    blue
@{animals}        cow    pig    dog
@{things}         ${animals}    ${colors}

*** Test Cases ***
Nested for loop example
    : FOR    ${x}    IN    @{animals}
    \    Keyword with for loop    ${x}

*** Keywords ***
Keyword with for loop
    [Arguments]    ${x}
    :FOR    ${y}    IN    @{colors}
    \    Log  The ${x} is ${y}
```

The credit goes to [ombre42](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2532697/ombre42). Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Possible way to simulate a two dimensional array is to make a list of strings and [split the string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32820905/how-to-split-strings-from-a-line-in-robot-framework) as you use it. The advantage over a list of lists is that each row is defined as a single line so you won't make mistakes when adding or deleting rows.

This array uses a space as the delimiter. Depending on your data you might have to use another delimiter.

```
*** Settings ***
Library                 String

*** Variables ***
# 3 columns per row
@{DATA}    1.0 2.2 30.0
...        2.0 5.5 1.0
...       32.0 6.1 1.4

*** Keywords ***
Using Line
    [Arguments]     ${line}
    @{data}=   Split String   ${line}
    Log   @{data}[0]   console=yes
    
*** Test cases ***
Using All Lines
    :FOR   ${line}   IN   @{DATA}
    \    Using Line   ${line}
```