# How to split strings from a line in robot framework

Tags: robotframework

How to get rest of the values from the variable

```
${random employee}= Convert To String   ${random emp}   
${replace}= Remove String Using Regexp  ${random employee}  ['\\[\\]\\,]

${splitline}=   Fetch From Left ${replace}  ${SPACE}
```

Output:

`${replace}  Alagu  kartest1234+3alagu@gmail.cokartest1234+3ramu@gmail.com Developer Team B3 Team lead`

```
${splitline} = Alagu
```

How to get rest of the values from the variable ${replace}

Answer (score 6):

Keyword `Split String` from `String` [standard library](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/#standard-libraries) does this.

```
Split String    string, separator=None, max_split=-1
```

> Splits the string using *separator* as a delimiter string.

> If a *separator* is not given, any whitespace string is a separator. In that case also possible consecutive whitespace as well as leading and trailing whitespace is ignored.

> Split words are returned as a list. If the optional *max_split* is given, at most *max_split* splits are done, and the returned list will have maximum *max_split + 1* elements.

**Examples:**

```
@{words} =  Split String    ${string}           
@{words} =  Split String    ${string}       ,${SPACE}
```

To get single values from `@{words}` use common array syntax: `@{words}[i]`. `i` is the index of the selected value. Indexes start from zero.

**Update:**
Since Robot Framework 3.1 the way to access an item in list is: **$**{words}[i].

Comment: @{words} = Split String ${replace} ,${SPACE}                   output: @{word}  Alagu  kartest1234+3alagu@gmail.cokartest1234+3ramu@gmail.com Developer Team B3 Team lead                                                                                        how to get devleoper team or  b3 from here

Comment: can anyone tell me how to get the value from @{words}

Comment: if i use    ${pick}= Get From List @{words}    2                                              output :${pick}  a                                                                                               i want the full text like Developer Team

Comment: What do exactly you want to get from output and what do you want to do with it?

Comment: @karthikas I added info how you get single values from `@{words}`.